# MYSQL ordering by matches not working

Tags: mysql, database, select

I'm trying to order by matches, but I'm unable to do so. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * , (( image LIKE  '%one%' ) + ( image LIKE  '%two%' )) 
AS matches
FROM images
ORDER BY matches
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?  The query looks correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff matches is not a column name.

Comment: . . It is an alias, and aliases are recognized in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @frosty could you please post the error or further explain the nature of your problem. 'not working' provides little detail to help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you want `matches DESC` in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (( image LIKE  '%one%' ) + ( image LIKE  '%two%' ))  as matches
FROM images i
ORDER BY matches DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: the reason why this works is because false is 0 which is less than true (which is 1). so desc puts the true results first in the answer.